# Connect multiple Phone's hotspot to one PC

Tags: networking

I am trying to connect 2 phones to a PC wireless.

The issue is that when I use a router connected to a PC and to the phones using wifi, it will **prevent the phones from going to internet with mobile data**, and I need 4G connection to internet.

Using only one phone is working properly, since I can do wifi hotspot from the phone, the phone will than go with the 4G and will also be connected with the PC with wifi dongle.

The issue is that any hotspot will have the same ip address - **192.168.43.1**, as it is hard coded in code. So connecting 2 phones to same pc will have 2 gateways with **same IP.**

What is the proper solution ?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities if one or both of your phones are rooted. You need 4G on both phones?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Hi, I can't root the phone ... I need to go 4G on both phones and connect with PC on ADB with WIFI/BT.

Comment: Then create hotspot on PC (if WiFi dongle supports AP mode), connect both phones to that. Since there won't be internet connectivity from PC side, both phones will also keep connected to 4G ( not sure if this behavior has been persistent on previous Android releases).

Comment: " ( not sure if this behavior has been persistent on previous Android releases)"
No it will not connect to internet unfortuntly. it will try go from wifi even 4G is working and wifi no.

Comment: It works for me on Android 9. Whenever WiFi drop connectivity to internet, 4G automatically starts working. Try setting *“Mobile data always active”* in Developer options. Otherwise rooting is the only solution.

Comment: I use Xiami Go and andorid 8